# Pascal Runtime error 216 at $004014AD

Tags: pascal

```
const
  SIZE = 100000;

var
  n, i, j: LongInt;
  a: array[1..SIZE, 1..SIZE] of Integer;
begin
  Read(n);

  for i:= 1 to n do
    for j:= 1 to n do;
      a[i][j]:= 0;
end.
```

Comment: Take this ";" out of the second loop, @IGOR_IGOR. This is your problem, for sure.

Comment: Pascal's integers are 16-bits wide. An array of 100,000x100,000 integers will occupy 18.6 GB of continuous memory, which I'm pretty sure you don't have.

Comment: @ Ed de Almeida: Yes and no. The main problem was (as Frédéric Hamidi) stated the memory usage.

Comment: @AlexanderBaltasar In terms of syntax, I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.
I assume that you'll never input 100000 values on the commandline :-)
I changed this value to something more realistic (which doesn't take to much memory...)

```
const
  SIZE = 100;

var
  n, i, j: integer;
  a: array[1..SIZE, 1..SIZE] of Integer;
begin
  Read(n);

  for i:= 1 to n do
    for j:= 1 to n do // here you had a semicolon!
      a[i][j]:= 0;
end.
```

Besides this, your code does nothing usefuf. It just assigns 0 to the array and quits.

You should also check if your input (n) exceeds the maximum size of the array (n>SIZE)

Comment: @downvoter: What can I do to improve the answer? What are You missing?